# How to get the ID of a created channel in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm currently making a simple Ticket System for my Bot and I want to send a Message to the new Channel my Bot created after clicking on a Button. The Channel create and everything else worked fine, but I don't know how to get the Channel ID from that new Channel. Does anyone know more than me? (I'm using discord.js v14)
Code from the Event after clicking on the Button:

```js
const { EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    data: {
        name: 'panelbutton'
    },
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        client.config = require('../../config');

        const ticketchannel = interaction.guild.channels.create({
            name: `${interaction.user.username}`,
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: interaction.guild.id,
                    deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel]
                },
                {
                    id: interaction.user.id,
                    allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages],
                    deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.UseApplicationCommands]
                }
            ]
        });

        const wait = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Created! :white_check_mark:')
            .setDescription(`Your Channel is created!`)
            .setTimestamp(Date.now())
            .setFooter({
                text: client.config.bot.footer
            });

        await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [wait], ephemeral: true
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Promise.Prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) or create a variable to define the channel created, which you already did.

`Promise.Prototype.then()`:

```js
await interaction.guild.channels.create({
    name: `${interaction.user.username}`,
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: interaction.guild.id,
            deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel]
        },
        {
            id: interaction.user.id,
            allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages],
            deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.UseApplicationCommands]
        }
    ]
}).then(channel => {
    const channelID = channel.id
    console.log(channelID)
})
```

Creating a variable:

```js
const ticketChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create({
    name: `${interaction.user.username}`,
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: interaction.guild.id,
            deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel]
        },
        {
            id: interaction.user.id,
            allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages],
            deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.UseApplicationCommands]
        }
    ]
})

const ticketChannelID = ticketChannel.id
```

Answer (score 2):

`interaction.guild.channels.create` returns a Promise resolving to a [`GuildChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildChannel) object which has an `id` property.

Add `await` before `interaction.guild.channels.create` and you should be able to access the ID using `ticketchannel.id`.